# DocuSign envelopes is not available after some days

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

I had created numbers of envelopes through REST API C#. Now I tired to check the status of those envelopes and found that all envelopes which were created are not available. I was not able to get any information of those envelope through REST API. And mostly old envelopes were not available and some of them are completed/signed.

Is that possible envelopes get deleted/expired from account after some days and we cannot get any information of those envelopes even signed envelopes? [120 days are default expiration time as per reminder & expiration settings]

I am not giving any code of REST API here because I think I am fine with that. Is any different method of REST API to get information on expired envelope?

I have not checked this scenario on production account. I am just using https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: Are you able to see the envelopes by logging in from the admin console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer Sandbox will only retain data upto 30 days.

Documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/company/terms-and-conditions/sandbox)

Comment: thanks... so it will not happen on production account if user have sufficient plan rt?

Comment: In production account, data will never be deleted by DocuSign. Only the user has the control to do it.